# how to get modulo of a value in exponential form

Tags: math, modulus

Question is about the modulo operator on very large numbers.

For example consider a question where the total number of permutations are to be calculated.
Consider a number of 90 digits with each of the 9 numbers (1 to 9) repeating 10 times
so `90!/(10!)^9)` is to be calculated

After reading many answers on StackOverflow I used logarithms to do it.

Now consider the log value to be 1923.32877864.

Now my question is how can I display the answer (i.e. 10 ^ log10(value) ) modulo of "m"?

And is this the best method for calculating the possible number of permutations?

**Edit**
Got the solution :)

Thanks to duedl0r.

Did it the way you specified using Modular Multiplicative Inverse.**Thanks :)**

Comment: Is `m` an integer that fits in 31 bit?

Comment: Is `m` prime, or at least coprime to `10!`?

Comment: yes it fits in 31bit .. 10^9 at most .

Comment: m is 10^9+7 for this particular question (its from a spoj site)

Comment: If you actually need an integer modulus, then using logs is the WRONG way to do it. Note that the result WILL be an integer, so you might just use a big integer form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is actually possible and correct, but let me summarize my comments and extend the answer from Miky Dinescu.

As Miky already wrote:

> a × b ≣<sub>m</sub> a<sub>m</sub> × b<sub>m</sub>

You can use this in your equality:

> 90! / 10!^9 ≣<sub>m</sub> x

Calculate each term:

> 90!<sub>m</sub> / 10!^9<sub>m</sub> ≣<sub>m</sub> x

Then find out your [multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) from 10!^9<sub>m</sub>. Then multiplicate the inverse with 90!<sub>m</sub>.

---

**update**
This seems to be correct (at least for this case :)). I checked with wolfram:

[(90!/10!^9) mod (10^9+7)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2890!/10!%2a%2a9%29%20mod%20%2810%2a%2a9%2b7%29) = 998551163

This leads to the same result:

[90! mod (10^9+7)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=90!%20mod%20%2810%2a%2a9%2b7%29) = 749079870
[10!^9 mod (10^9+7)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10!%2a%2a9%20mod%20%2810%2a%2a9%2b7%29) = 220052161

do the inverse:

[(220052161 * x) mod(10^9+7) = 1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28220052161%20%2a%20x%29%20mod%2810%5E9%2b7%29%20=%201) = 23963055

then:

[(749079870*23963055) mod (10^9+7)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28749079870%2a23963055%29%20mod%20%2810%5E9%2b7%29) = 998551163

No proof, but some evidence that it might work :)

Comment: Got the solution :)
Thanks to duedl0r.
Did it the way you specified using Modular Multiplicative Inverse 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the way to compute the total number of permutations modulo `m`, where m is an arbitrary integer (usually chosen to be a large prime number) is to use the following property:

```
 (a * b) % m = ((a % m) * (b % m)) % m
```

Considering that the total number of permutations of N is `N! = 1 * 2 * 3 * .. * N`, if you need to compute `N! % m`, you can essentially apply the property above for multiplication modulo m, and you have:

```
 ((((1 * (2 % m)) % m) * (3 % m)) % m) * ..
```

**EDIT**

In order to compute the 90! / (10! ^ 9) value you could simplify the factors and then use multiplication modulo m to compute the final result modulo m.

Here's what I'm thinking:

90! = 10! * (11 * 12 * .. * 20) * (21 * 22 * .. * 30) * .. * (81 * 82 * .. * 90)

You can then rewrite the original expression as:

(10! * (11 * 12 * .. * 20) * (21 * 22 * .. * 30) * .. * (81 * 82 * .. * 90)) / (10! * 10! * ... * 10!)

At the numerator, you have a product of 9 factors - considering each expression in parenthesis a factor. The same is true for the denominator (you have 9 factors, each equal to 10!).

The first factor at the denominator is trivial to simplify. After that you still have 8 pairs that need simplification.

So, you can factor each term of the products and simplify the denominator away. For example:

11 * 12 * 13 * 14 * 15 * 16 * 17 * 18 * 19 * 20 <=> 11 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 13 * 2 * 7 * 3 * 5 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 17 * 2 * 9 * 2 * 2 * 5

The denominator will always be: 2 * 3 * 2 * 2 * 5 * 2 * 3 * 7 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 2 * 5

After the simplification the second pair reduces to : 2 * 2 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19

The same can be applied to each subsequent pair and you will end up with a simple product that can be computed modulo m using the formula above.

Of course, efficiently implementing the algorithm to perform the simplification will be tricky so ultimately there has to be a better way that eludes me now.

Comment: How do you calculate `90!/10!^9` with this? `(90! % m) / 10!^9` doesn't look right.. or even if you take `10^1923.32` you run into problems, since 1923.32 is not an even number..

Comment: exactly as duedl0r told. that is the problem i m facing .how can i work with divisions .. if done ,mostly its resulting 0, as numerator  < denominator .

Comment: I think you can multiply by 10!^9. But it's not mentioned in this solution.. something like this: 90!%m = x*(10!^9%m) %m. Then search for an `x` :)

Comment: maybe you can even use euler to get the inverse.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: hmm, I guess I missed out an important aspect of your question @anudeep2011. I remember there being a method for computing modular exponentiaion with non-integer exponents but I can't remember exactly how it goes.  Modular exponentiation with integer exponents is easy..